# Data is not received on PHP page using $.POST() method of jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .post

My POST variable at PHP page is always empty still after clicking on submit button. I send data from a javascript page to php page.

Javascript code:

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
    if(quantityArray[j] == undefined){
        alert("Empty Form can not be submitted!");
    }
    else {
        $.post('insert_man_order.php',{ total_price: quantityArray[j] }, function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
    }
});
```

The PHP code where i should receive the value of variable total_price is:

```
if(isset($_POST['total_price'])){
        $price = $_POST['total_price'];
    }
    else{
        echo "No data recieved";
    }
```

One more thing here.. I have written alert by passing data into it in $.post function and it works perfect. So if data is received perfectly after passing it to another page than whats the problem in receiving it at another page?

Comment: check in console (using firebug) if your js code is making an AJAX request or not

Comment: If its not making than how it is possible that it should alert out data variable..??? the data variable is something we get after if completes the request.

Comment: echo you must return data by echoing it otherwise you will always receive empty string in your alert

Comment: what you are receiving in alert?

Comment: yeah but when i alert out 'data' than i get the value of quantityArray[j].. Isn't so that data variable should be something which brings answer of the request from that php page..??

Comment: I dint get your problem statement. can you brief it more in terms of what you want and what is happening ?

Comment: yeah sure..

I don't want the data back on the page from where i requested it. But i want to receive the data on the page where i sended. So in this case i want the value of quantityArray[j] on my another PHP page. the code of that php page is written above. The problem is I don't recieve the data which i am sending through jQuery.

Comment: means you are not receiving data in `$_POST['total_price']` on `insert_man_order.php`

Comment: Yes exactly.. i am not receiving data in $_POST['total_price'] on insert_man_order.php

Comment: can you var_dump your $_POST and share the result

Comment: I am out of station right now.. will share it asap!!!

Comment: Ok I have got what is the issue here... I am sending the data to the php page when user clicks on submit button. So once the submit button is clicked the user sends the data to php page and stores it in the $_POST['total_price'] on insert_man_order.php . And than it bring backs the data which is being echo out on that page. Than the PHP performs it operation and sends the data again using POST method in FORM. So that page insert_man_order.php is refreshed and my POST variable is empty... So what is solution for it..???

Comment: if you want to keep the information through out the user session use `$_SEESION`

Comment: I got you! Anyways the best solution for me was to use PHP as the whole when submitting the form. I was trying to send one variable with jQuery and rest with PHP and was messing up between this 2 languages. Made it more simpler.! Thnks for the HELP yiiframe

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if (isset($_POST['total_price'])) {
        $price = $_POST['total_price'];
}
else {
        echo "No data recieved";
}
```

do this

```
if (isset($_POST['total_price'])) {
        echo $_POST['total_price'];
}
else {
        echo "No data received";
}
```

you must print the data to make an ajax response.

Comment: I don't where it was messing up the things but my problem was solved when i used jQuery ajax function instead of http request.

Comment: after using ajax method also things are not getting up.. :(